# Binding dbcontext to gridview and displaying data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspxgridview

I have a gridview:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="ParentSelect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="ParentSelect_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="ParentSelect_RowCreated" emptydatatext="Please Submit A Clip. C'mon dude." ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="600" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black"   />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="dbContext.Mains.VideoUrl" HeaderText="Title" Visible="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and I have binded my DBCONTEXT:

```
       protected void LoadGrid()
    {
        ParentSelect.DataSource = dbContext.Mains.ToList(); 
        ParentSelect.DataBind();
    }
```

How do I display columns without the column names that come from the database.

For example when I had autogeneratecolumns set to "true" it would display the column names from the database, but instead I want to display the same data in the column with a different name.

so instead of VideoUrl (name of db column) I want to mask it somehow so the data comes from videourl but it has another name like "URL".

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it on the RowDataBound event

```
protected void ParentSelect_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) 
    { 
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "URL"; 
    } 
}
```